# Why does Jest try running my whole app rather than the imported modules?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app

When I am trying to test a react component, I get errors from other components that are not imported into the tested module.

I would expect these errors to occur if I had imported the module as I am currently refactoring a lot of code and haven't got round to these files yet.

It's almost as if Jest is running all of my components before testing.
Here is one of the test files that cause this issue:

```
import React from 'react';
import { LoginPage } from 'components';

describe('Login Page', () => {
  it('should render', () => {
    expect(shallow(<LoginPage />)).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
  it('should use background passed into props', () => {
    const image = 'bg.png';
    const expected = {
      backgroundImage: image
    };
    const wrapper = shallow(<LoginPage background={image} />);
    expect(wrapper.prop('style')).toEqual(expected);
  });
});
```

Loginpage.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { LoginForm } from 'components';
import './LoginPage.css';

type Props = { background: string , logInRequest: Function};

const LoginPage = ({ background, logInRequest }: Props) => (
  <div className="login-page" style={{backgroundImage: background}}>
    <LoginForm submit={logInRequest}/>
  </div>
);
```

Here is `setupTests.js`

```
import Enzyme, { shallow, mount, render } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import localStorage from 'mock-local-storage';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

global.requestAnimationFrame = function(callback) {
  setTimeout(callback, 0);
};

global.shallow = shallow;
global.mount = mount;
global.render = render;
console.log = () => ({});
```

Stack trace:

```
  at invariant (node_modules/invariant/invariant.js:42:15)
  at wrapWithConnect (node_modules/react-redux/lib/components/connectAdvanced.js:101:29)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/containers/ApplicationList/ApplicationList.js:8:42)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/containers/index.js:9:41)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/CustomerDashboard/CustomerDashboard.js:2:19)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/index.js:14:43)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/LoginPage/LoginPage.test.js:2:19)
      at <anonymous>
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

From reading the stack trace, I can assume that Jest is checking the list of exports inside `components/index.js` and `containers/index.js`.

Why is jest concerned with errors coming from a list of exports? I am not importing `containers/ApplicationList` into `LoginPage`, it is only referenced as a dependency through the list of exports.

I have found that if I remove `CustomerDashboard` from the export list, the issue goes away which says to me it's not an issue with importing into `LoginPage`

Should I be using a relative import like `import LoginPage from './LoginPage` with the test in the same directory as `LoginPage` rather than `import { LoginPage } from 'components'`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you `import` a module, it will resolve all it's dependencies. Your `AppWrap` must import `PaymentAccountForm` at some point.

You can enable [auto mock](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#automock-boolean) to narrow the depth, or you can mock all sub module manually with [jest.mock](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) both will replace module with a mocked version when it is being required.

Comment: So If I have `import module from 'components';`, will everything in `components/index.js` be resolved too? With `components/index.js` being a list of exports. I think that's what is happening based on what you've said as I am getting similar issues with multiple components.

Comment: Yes, everything that's exported. Imports are static and resolved immediatly when the file is loaded, even if the file is not used.

Comment: So I should be using a relative path to the file like `'./component'` rather than 'components' to avoid errors from dependencies?

Comment: Or you can `import { module } from 'components';` this way only `module` is loaded.

Comment: Sorry, the lack of a curly brace in my initial comment was a typo. I have improved the question and added a new example with the same issue happening. Maybe that will help with explaining better

Comment: Ho my last comment seems to be wrong then, other imports gets resolved anyway. Jest is not actually running all your components, it's just resolving the dependencies.

Comment: What you need to do is to import {module} from "components/Loginpage", so that you skip the index.js and all its imports.

Note that if you are "export ... from ...", this is actually also an import.